# Copying notes, bookmarks, highlighting, etc. added to a .pdf file on a Kindle to computer or other kindle

Tags: kindle, pdf

I am using K2pdfopt to reflow the content of scientific papers (that are in .pdf format) so that they are formatted for my Kindle. On my Kindle, I add bookmarks, highlighting and notes to the papers as I read them. I would like to copy these annotated K2pdfopt pdf files back to my computer so I can preserve them including the the notes and marks I have made on the Kindle, but when I copy these files back to my notebook and open them with the Kindle app on my computer, the notes and marks are absent. How can I copy the annotated K2pdfopt pdf files back to my computer preserving the the notes and marks I have made on the Kindle?

Comment: Have you tried Exporting the Notes/Highlighting?
You can export them as an HTML file then share that file any way you like.